# How to use setter injection with Kotlin and Spring?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, kotlin, setter-injection

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the setter injection of Spring with Kotlin. I cannot use constructor injection for this because the Bean might be null and I don't want to use field injection because it's the worst. The obvious way to write

```
var x : Any? = null
    @Autowired
    set(value) {
        x = value
    }
```

cannot work because this will result in a cyclic call. So how can I autowire a member using setter injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this is a bit hard to find simply because I never wrote a setter for Kotlin so far. The problem is that one easily confuses the property with the [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) which is also generated by the compiler.

Thus the correct code is

```
var x : Any? = null
    @Autowired(required = false)
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

The `required = false` is necessary to make the injection optional, by the way.